# How to append string into the run time html attribute value using Java script/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML Code**

A)    `<input type="text" id="1" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black;" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">`

B)    `<input type="text" id="1O" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black; display:none" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">`

I need to change the display attribute of **B** to `'block'`.

**Solution attempted:**

```
var strNotApplicableControlName = $(htmControl).attr('id'); //return value is 1 (id of A)
strNotApplicableControlName = strNotApplicableControlName.concat("O");
//strNotApplicableControlName = strNotApplicableControlName + "O"; //Not working
//using js
document.getElementById(strNotApplicableControlName).style.display = 'block';
//using jQuery
$(strNotApplicableControlName).css('display','block');
$("'" + strNotApplicableControlName + "'").css('display','block');
```

**Output of concatination:**

```
"1"O
```

I am clueless to identify the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select element using `$('[id=1O]')` please look into below snippet to see how it works

```js
var dynamicid = 1;

$('[id='+dynamicid+'O]').css("display","block");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="1" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black;" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">
<input type="text" id="1O" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black; display:none" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">
```

Comment: Thanks. But  "1" is dynamic.

Comment: var strNAControlId = $(htmControl).attr('id').replace(/['"]+/g, '')
                    htmlControlNotApplicable = strNAControlId + "O";
                    var htmlControlNotApplicable = "\"" + htmlControlNotApplicable + "\"";
                    document.getElementById(htmlControlNotApplicable).style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById(htmlControlNotApplicable).value = "";

Comment: in your case `$('[id='+htmlControlNotApplicable+']')` this would be work

Comment: Sweet Sweet. It worked for me. Today, I learned something from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

$('#10').css('display','Block');

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('1O').style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<input type="text" id="1" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black;" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">

<input type="text" id="1O" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black; display:none" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">
```

Or Jquery:

```js
$('#1O').css('display', 'Block');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="1" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black;" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">

<input type="text" id="1O" name="Q-1>1>1=1" value="SELECT" style="width: 60px; height: 25px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border: 2px solid black; display:none" onfocus="this.blur()" onclick="getTriStateMarks(this)" ;="">
```